# Timing Ajax Requests - negative values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We have a small javascript test designed to test a clients network before they use our software. It works by making AJAX calls to our servers and gradually increasing the number of calls made per second and timing how long it takes to get a response back to give us an idea of latency as the network load increases.

In order to time the requests we are attaching a `sentTime` to the jqXhr object on jquerys `beforeSend` event then calculating the difference on complete. We simulate the load of multiple users by creating a list of times (just an array of ints), then setting the ajax request to fire using a setTimeout, like so:

```
function configureAjaxRequestTimings() {
    var time = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < requestMax; i++) {
        ajaxRequestTimings.push(time += getRandomTime());
    }
    that.totalRequestTime = time;
}

function getRandomTime() {
    return (Math.random() * 4000) + 3000; // generate new time (between 3 secs and 7 secs)
}

function StartRequests() {
    for (var j = 0, thisTime; thisTime = ajaxRequestTimings[j++];) {
        doAjaxRequest(thisTime);
    }
};


function doAjaxRequest(timeDelay) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: url,
            timeout: 60000,
            beforeSend: function (jqXhr) {
                jqXhr.sentTime = new Date().getTime();
            },
            complete: function (response) {
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                var requestTime = now - response.sentTime;
                requestTimes.push(requestTime);
            }
        });
    }, timeDelay)
}
```

However, we see very occasionally a negative time pushed to `requestTimes`, but I cannot see how this can happen (unless `complete` is called before `beforeSend`??). I am unable to recreate this issue on my dev environment. Is there perhaps some kind of clever inlining or similar performance tricks some browsers do that may cause this issue? (it only has happened twice so far both on chrome, the last one was on chrome 45)

Note: I am aware this method will not give precise millisecond timings (or even close) due to the single threaded nature of js, the idea is only to see the general 'shape' of the response curve under increasing load

Comment: `complete` cannot be called before `beforeSend`, if it was the case it would not result as negative value but `NaN` as `jqXhr.sentTime` would not be defined yet (`now - jqXhr.sentTime` -> `+new Date() - undefined`).

Comment: @Haketo `beforeSend` always executes before sending any request to the server and complete always gets executed after every `success/error` callbacks.

Comment: @Jai That's what I said, OP code cannot results with negative values (even if there was a bug that called `complete` before `beforeSend`).

Comment: @Hacketo That's what I thought but it has definitely happened in production

Comment: @Anduril then you should look around this code. With only this piece of code, `requestTimes` cannot have negatives values.

Comment: @Hacketo fair enough, I have added some more code around how the ajax requests are set up, but I don't think it's relevant (which is why I didn't bother including it initially)

Comment: the only way I see that `requestTimes` could hold negatives values is that `new Date().getTime()` is going lower

Comment: Do you store `sentTime` and `now` variables in your `log`/`db`? if so, what are the values for the negative numbers? if not, you can try to do so and see the result of these values. maybe this can help you somehow.

Comment: @EhsanT We don't store the values of `now` and `sentTime` but the client who recently received negative values after running the test got exactly one negative value in 3 out of 4 test runs. Values were -61ms, -102ms and -143ms. Its almost certainly something client related since this is very rare (we have had probably hundreds of clients run this test multiple times and only 2 have ever had it) and this client got 3.

Comment: I do not think it's logical that any browser tweak it's behavior like this. if so, it will definitely cause major breakdowns in many websites and portals. so, maybe there were something wrong with the clients `os` during sending the requests. as I can see each request time is exactly differed from the previous one -41ms. maybe you can log more parameters for some time and keep an eye on them to see if this case happens again.

Comment: @EhsanT I was thinking of an unrelated trick I know chrome uses with `setTimeout`. Usually because the callback is only added to the event queue after the delay, the action will fire after the delay + however long it take to bubble through the queue (which can be significant if the client is under load) so chrome tries to anticipate this and adds it to the event queue *before* the delay has completely elapsed to try and get it close to the delay specified. As a result, in chrome `setTimeout` can fire a little before the specified delay. Thought there might be something similar going on here